# Sklearn sees differently ordered data as different set

Tags: python, pyspark, scikit-learn, k-means

So I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.

They are exactly the same, except the order of rows is mixed between the two. For example:

df1:

```
 id   |  feat1   |  feat2   | 
 1    |    A     |    in    |
 2    |    B     |   out    |
 3    |    C     |   out    |
```

df2:

```
 id   |  feat1   |  feat2   | 
 3    |    C     |   out    |
 2    |    B     |   out    |
 1    |    A     |   in     |
```

I am building clustering algorithm with kmeans on this data. It is the case, that whenever I feed this differently ordered data to *pipeline.fit()*, I end up getting different results for this (different centroids).
Can anyone explain me how this issue happens and why ordering the data before fit fixes it?

Inside my pipeline there is a preprocessing part, which consists of:

```
('selector', FunctionTransformer(_select_data)),
('transformer', 
        FunctionTransformer(np.log1p,inverse_func=_invert_log_transform, 
        check_inverse=False)),
('scaler', QuantileTransformer(random_state=42)),
('pca', PCA(random_state=42))
```

And this is where I start noticing the difference - transformed data is already quite different. If I use ordered dataset, then it comes out the same.

Comment: It's due to randomization. Even if you have same dataset with random_state same but order is different then it will be different. To get same data everytime you need to pass in same order with same random_state. And if model is properly processed with appropriate data then only 5% up or down will be difference even if data is randomly ordered

Comment: @GodWin yes, but why exactly this happens..? It happens before clustering part of the algorithm, right after transformations. And it also never happens with synthetic data which is clearly clustered. Then even if I get slight differences in transformed data, and the order is not the same, I get same centroids. But if data is not clustered that well, and the order is mixed, my transformed data is different and centroids end up different. So at which point a position of row in data table is inportant, if in general feature space it's position does not change just because it's in a different row?

Comment: I think I found the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B

Basically because initialization is based on actual datapoints and it's chosen randomly from the dataset, mixing the order leads to different initializations even under same seed.

Comment: Without full code and a representative dataset it's hard to say. Try removing steps from the transformer pipeline to narrow it down; I suspect `_select_data`.